# var that = this, self = this, etc

Tags: javascript, scope, nested, this

The purpose of assigning a variable in this way is to provide access to active object within the parent scope when a nested scope exists. I think that this is rather poor form; why not provide a more meaningful variable name for the parent target object?

For example, if we select all div's in a page, and iterate over them. Within each div we select all anchor links within the target div, iterating over these anchor links in a nested loop. In this example, the "this" of the outer scope is the current target div, and the "this" of the inner scope would be the current target anchor link.

To create a hook into the active target div in the outer scope, I typically see:

```
var that = this;
```

Even in Crockford's Good-Parts book, he uses this assignment.

At risk of making a fool of myself by questioning this technique, why not something more meaningful, like

```
var outerDiv = this;
```

What do you think?

Comment: It's just a naming convention. Everytime I see something called `self` and `that`, I tend to know what it means, whilst if I saw `outerDiv` I'd have to search if it was a local variable for example.

Comment: @sachleen: you mean, "You can do _this_..." :)

Comment: The point is not to get the scope of outer object. It is to capture the scope of current object for later use when "this" has already exited.
The story goes: you load the page, the object runs and finishes. It says that when the user clicks on some button, a function of that object is called. But you can't use "this" anymore, because the function runs later, after the original object has already finished. Its' "this" is window or something. So we use get a "that" or "self" or "me" as a referrence to the object that created the later-running function in the first place.

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 3):

That's perfectly fine, but the way you talk about `this` being the variable iterated makes it sound like you're using jQuery. It's not always an element, and sometimes `that` makes the most sense:

```
function Constructor() {
    var that = this;

    this.eventListenerThatWillBeBound = function() {
        // Do something with that
    };
}
```

So... use whatever's clearest in the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should name variables in a manner that makes sense to you.

People use conventions because then they can immediately recognize it as representing a common scenario, as can other people reading the code.

If you don't like the conventional way of doing things, do it your own way, but make sure your variables make sense to others reading your code.

---

FWIW, `self` is a reference to the global context in browsers, so it makes sense to some people to shadow the `self` variable with the nearest outer context, by doing `self = this`.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly do it like this

```
function() {
  // use 'this' as it is 
}.bind(this)
```

Or I call the closure with the scope from outside

```
closure.call(this); // the scope inside the closure is now 'this' too
```

I don't need funny names then.